# No scroll bar button in Chrome browser

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

Suddenly scrollbar have no buttons anymore in my chrome browser. I have tried to turn off all extensions, but without any result.

[image] Any ideas?

Comment: As a last option you may try a Reinstall.

Comment: If it's only chrome doing it, reinstalling Chrome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind of magic. I have deleted top level files and dbs in the chrome profile folder and it works now. It looks like I had a crash, because there some temporary files and maybe broken dbs.

[image]